# Join Multiple Relations by Different Fields

Tags: apache-pig

Say I have three files `data1`, `data2` and `assocs`:

```
$ cat data1
key1,foo
key2,bar
$ cat data2
key3,braz
key4,froz
$ cat assoc 
key1,key3
key2,key4
```

I load these files via

```
$ pig -b -p debug=WARN -x local
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Apache Pig version 0.10.0 (r1328203) compiled Apr 19 2012, 22:54:12
Logging error messages to: /home/vince/tmp/pig_1355407390166.log
Connecting to hadoop file system at: file:///
grunt> data1 = load 'data1' using PigStorage(',') as (key: chararray, val: chararray);  
grunt> data2 = load 'data2' using PigStorage(',') as (key: chararray, val: chararray);  
grunt> assoc = load 'assoc' using PigStorage(',') as (key1: chararray, key2: chararray);
```

What I want is a relation that looks like:

```
(foo, braz)
(bar, froz)
```

That is

```
data1_val, data1_key <-> assoc_key1, assoc_key2 <-> data2_key, data2_val
```

Comment: My solution: -First step: join data1 with assoc, -Second step join result with data2. I would use a unique name for all fields, that makes it easier.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and don't get it right and I have no glue what I am doing wrong. I tried `join1 = join data1 by key, assoc by key1;`, but `dump join1` doesn't yield any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = join data1 by key, assoc by key1;
B = join A by assoc::key2, data2 by key;
RES = foreach B generate A::data1::val, data2::val;
```

Comment: Doing this followed by `dump RES;` doesn't yield any results on Pig 0.10.

Comment: You need to define the correct delimiter when loading the files, e.g: `data1 = load 'data1' using PigStorage(',') as (key: chararray, val: chararray);`

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot! Have been struggling with this for over one day now :/