# Joining multiple relations using a common field in Pig not giving any output

Tags: apache-pig

I have two relations r1 and r2.

```
grunt>describe r1;
r1: {f1: chararray,ts: chararray}

grunt>describe r2;
r2: {f2:chararray,ts: chararray}
```

I want to join the two relations on ts to get an output like this

```
(f1,f2)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861570/join-multiple-relations-by-different-fields) is what I tried (did not find the comments relevant to my case).

```
grunt>j = join r1 by ts,r2 by ts;
grunt>O = foreach j generate CONCAT(r1::f1,r2::f2);
grunt>describe O;
O: {chararray}
grunt>dump O;
```

I am not getting any output on dump O. I am new to pig so please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the data I'm using :

data1

```
 f1a    10
 f1b    12
```

data2

```
 f2a    10
 f2b    11
 f2c    12
```

If I run the following script, it produces the expected result:

```
 grunt> a = LOAD 'data1' as (f1:chararray, ts:int);
 grunt> b = LOAD 'data2' as (f2:chararray, ts:int);

 grunt> c = JOIN a BY ts, b BY ts;
 grunt> DESCRIBE c;
 c: {a::f1: chararray,a::ts: int,b::f2: chararray,b::ts: int}

 grunt> d = FOREACH c GENERATE CONCAT(f1, f2);
 grunt> DUMP d
 (f1af2a)
 (f1bf2c)
```

Comment: I am sorry about the typo. It is not there in the program that was executed.

Comment: I edit my solution and give a complete working exemple.